PowerApps, Data is written in a wrong way (Patch)
I have this function:
Patch(
    participant;
    Defaults(participant);
    {
        Titel: DataCardValue13.Text;
        lastName: DataCardValue14.Text;
        street: DataCardValue15.Text;
        postcode: DataCardValue16.Value;
        location: DataCardValue17.Text;
        sex: (1);
        yearOfBirth: "TestBrith";
        country: DataCardValue20.Text;
        language: DataCardValue21.Text;
        restaurant: DataCardValue22.Text;
        comments: DataCardValue23.Text;
        employeeId: Text(User().EntraObjectId);
        registerDate: Today();
        vip: (0)
    }
)

It is located in the OnSuccess() function from my Form. All the corresponding field exist (They are marked with color). I also double checked the spelling from the matching table (participant). Now if I fill out the form, instead of one new entry with all the data, I get many wrong entries with blank fields.
See Image:

Ty for helping and ask if anything is unclear.
Kind Regards
Patrick
What I already tried:
I double checked the names, the fields and also the datatypes, I restarted my machine multiple times.

I think you need to code on OnSelect event instead of OnSuccess().
